# Why is Spree not rendering my changed template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, spree, spree-auth-devise

Working on a Spree Commerce app with Rails and trying to customise the templates on the frontend. I have cloned the frontend templates library and they are located in my `app/views/spree` directory, but when I make a change there it is not rendered in development. I can successfully add products in the admin panel so I'm convinced it has installed correctly.

I can make a change in the css by changing the  `app/assets/stylesheets/frontend` `.css` files, but none of the `.html.erb` files seem be rendered properly.

Link to my code:

https://github.com/bashford7/sbc_spree

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to reboot the server after every change in html or css...